# Date Range Look up, Returned Value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am searching a range of cells that contain dates.  I want the formula to examine if any of the said dates are before a specified date.  If the statement is true I want the formula to put yes in the cell, if false i want the formula to put no in the cell

```
=IF(COUNTIF('ESU1'!D3:D50,"<date(2014,1,1)"),"Yes","No")
```

Based on the cells range there are dates before specified date but returning the fals results of "No"

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF('ESU1'!D3:D50,"<"&DATE(2014,1,1)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: what did the quotations and ampersand do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the placement of the second double quotes and use the ampersand `&`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('ESU1'!D3:D50,"<"&DATE(2014,1,1)),"Yes","No")
```

If `<date(2014,1,1)` is enclosed within the quotes as you currently have it, it is evaluated as *text*. Moving the quotes and using the ampersand separates the operator `<` and the `DATE` function, which is now evaluated, and now the `COUNTIF` will do a time comparison and not look for the *text* `<date(2014,1,1)`.